# Word.Range cannot find assembly reference

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to use C# to create a Table in Microsoft Word 2010.  The example code shown below cannot find the assembly reference. Does anyone know the assembly reference for Word or am I missing a namespace?

The exact error that I am getting is "The type or namespace name 'Word' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
//I have added these directives but I am still getting an error below
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;

object start = 0;
object end = 0;

//The Word is giving a build error saying no assembly reference can be found
Word.Range tableLocation = this.Range(ref start, ref end);
this.Tables.Add(tableLocation, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Did you look in the documentation for any of the types you want to use? For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range(v=office.15).aspx MSDN tells you which assembly a type is in...

Comment: Well that namespace is declared in code, but still getting an error on Word.range

Comment: Yes, because you need an assembly reference... Again, look at the documentation. (I think you should probably go through a tutorial on how to do interop with Word...)

Comment: The two Assembly references that I have added are Microsoft.Office.Interop.Wrod and Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.

Comment: Well if you've already added an assembly reference, I'd expect it to be okay. Please edit your question to give details of the assemblies you've added and the *precise* error message. (Do you definitely need both of those assemblies, btw?)

Comment: Just as a side note: there is a difference between adding an `assembly reference` and adding a `using directive`. Are you aware of that?

Comment: no whats the difference? Please explain

Comment: Jon is the directive what I declare in the actual code, and the Assembly Reference is what I add to the Reference Folder in the Solution Explorer? Correct?

Comment: @tennis779 yes, this is how you could explain it. You need both add the assemly reference so that your project knows the assemly and make the required namespaces visible to your class via using directives.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 references that have to be attached:

1. `Microsoft.Interop.Word` dll from the GAC tab.
2. `Microsoft Office Object Library` dll from the COM tab.

Hope this helps.